# Learning by doing a project

Tags: c#

I have typed up some code to try and practice what I have learned in my programming course.  Something is wrong with my logic as I am not getting the answer I am supposed to get.

I have searched and google and rewatched the training videos but nothing seems to help.

```
namespace TenPinBowling 
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write("Would you like to bowl, Y or N: ");
                var answer = Console.ReadLine();

                if (answer == "n")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Thanks for playing, press any to exit :)");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    break;

                }

                Score();                
            }
        }

        static void Score()
        {

            {
                Random pins = new Random();
                var pinsKnockedDown = pins.Next(0, 10);
                //var totalScore = 0;

                Console.WriteLine("You bowled a: " + pinsKnockedDown);

                //var result = totalScore + pinsKnockedDown;

                Console.WriteLine("You're total score is: " + Tally(pinsKnockedDown));


            }
        }

        static int Tally(int score)
        {
            {
                int result = 0;
                result = result + score;
                return result;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I was hoping my second method would keep a running total of my score but it resets to the individual score every time.

Comment: And what is the response you supposed to get?

Comment: You're not saving the total anywhere and always adding the score to zero.

Comment: Even though the Tally function is static it’s local variables are initialized on every call.  Your result variable needs to be declared somewhere else.

Comment: You increment nothing `int result = 0;result = result + score;` because result is zero, `result = 0 + score`

Comment: declare result outside `Tally`

Comment: I would strongly advice against unnecesary `{}` or `()`. If you keep your code simple it will be more easier to read and easier to mantain. I mean `{ {` should be `{`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In

```
static int Tally(int score)
        {
            {
                int result = 0;
                result = result + score;
                return result;
            }
        }
```

you create a *new* local variable `result` each time you invoke the method, so the record of past scores is lost. Making `result` a field of the class would allow it to persist for the duration of the game. A minimal code change might be:

```
private static int result = 0;

static int Tally(int score)
{
    result = result + score;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: (I'm aware that there are a lot of other suggestions that could be made, but this should at least solve the problem!)

Comment: Yes, such as "*why the nested `{{ }}`?*" or "*you can write `result += score;` instead of `result = result + score;`*" or again "*you're creating a new `Random` everytime you call `Score()`, better use the same one*". Still solving the immediate problem OP was facing :)

Answer (score 0):

I would guess you always need to keep track of your total score, if it should not reset. Right now you always add the current score to zero (in Tally). If you put `int result` outside of tally it should keep track accordingly.